# Search and replace http:// to https:// 10x my database size

Tags: database

I did a search and replace using the WP plugin to change all URLs from http:// to https:// which seems to have made my database 10 x the size.  My host is complaining and I also want to understand what's happened as a smaller database is better.

Could it be regex related because I didn't escape the :// or something?

Is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You backed up your original database? If so, first I would restore it so it gets your host off your back.

Comment: Look at the plugin source code, what queries is it running? What was your regex?

Comment: @sandrodz I didn't use a regex

Comment: @cedon the backup wouldn't restore to localhost which scares me

Comment: In any case I still want to replace https to avoid any mixed content warnings

Comment: You can actually use `.htaccess` to do it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www

Comment: I already do this but for some reason some things are mixed content still